Encounter a cythonize error while installing py-earth
I encounter following cythonize error while I install the py-earth from git in an virtual env (python 3.8.19).
What I did is,
git clone git://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth.git
cd py-earth
python setup.py install --cythonize

but it throws me some error, which looks like cython compiling error, (I am not very familiar with Cython...) and my current cython version is (3.0.10), by run pip install --upgrade cython
The error message is attached as follows, can anyone help me with this please? Many thank!
Compiling pyearth/_util.pyx because it changed.
Compiling pyearth/_basis.pyx because it changed.
Compiling pyearth/_record.pyx because it changed.
Compiling pyearth/_pruning.pyx because it changed.
Compiling pyearth/_forward.pyx because it changed.
Compiling pyearth/_knot_search.pyx because it changed.
Compiling pyearth/_qr.pyx because it changed.
Compiling pyearth/_types.pyx because it changed.
[1/8] Cythonizing pyearth/_basis.pyx
/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:381: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /Users/username/Projects/Projects/py-earth/pyearth/_basis.pxd
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cpython cimport bool
cimport numpy as cnp
from _types cimport FLOAT_t, INT_t, INDEX_t, BOOL_t
^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pxd:3:0: '_types.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cpython cimport bool
cimport numpy as cnp
from _types cimport FLOAT_t, INT_t, INDEX_t, BOOL_t
^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pxd:3:0: '_types/FLOAT_t.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cpython cimport bool
cimport numpy as cnp
from _types cimport FLOAT_t, INT_t, INDEX_t, BOOL_t
^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pxd:3:0: '_types/INT_t.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cpython cimport bool
cimport numpy as cnp
from _types cimport FLOAT_t, INT_t, INDEX_t, BOOL_t
^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pxd:3:0: '_types/INDEX_t.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cpython cimport bool
cimport numpy as cnp
from _types cimport FLOAT_t, INT_t, INDEX_t, BOOL_t
^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pxd:3:0: '_types/BOOL_t.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    cpdef bint make_unsplittable(BasisFunction self)

    cpdef list get_children(BasisFunction self)
    
    cpdef BasisFunction get_coverage(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable)
                                                         ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pxd:31:57: 'INDEX_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    cpdef list get_children(BasisFunction self)
    
    cpdef BasisFunction get_coverage(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable)
    
    cpdef bool has_linear(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable)
                                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pxd:33:46: 'INDEX_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    
    cpdef BasisFunction get_coverage(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable)
    
    cpdef bool has_linear(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable)
    
    cpdef bool linear_in(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable)
                                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pxd:35:45: 'INDEX_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    cpdef prune(BasisFunction self)

    cpdef unprune(BasisFunction self)

    cpdef knots(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable)
                                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pxd:47:36: 'INDEX_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    cpdef unprune(BasisFunction self)

    cpdef knots(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable)

    cpdef INDEX_t effective_degree(BasisFunction self)
          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pxd:49:10: 'INDEX_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    cpdef knots(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable)

    cpdef INDEX_t effective_degree(BasisFunction self)

    cpdef apply(BasisFunction self, cnp.ndarray[FLOAT_t, ndim=2] X,
                                                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pxd:51:48: Invalid type.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport numpy as cnp
from _types cimport FLOAT_t, INT_t, INDEX_t, BOOL_t

cdef FLOAT_t log2(FLOAT_t x)
     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_util.pxd:4:5: 'FLOAT_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport numpy as cnp
from _types cimport FLOAT_t, INT_t, INDEX_t, BOOL_t

cdef FLOAT_t log2(FLOAT_t x)
                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_util.pxd:4:18: 'FLOAT_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport numpy as cnp
from _types cimport FLOAT_t, INT_t, INDEX_t, BOOL_t

cdef FLOAT_t log2(FLOAT_t x)

cpdef apply_weights_2d(cnp.ndarray[FLOAT_t, ndim=2] B,
                                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_util.pxd:6:35: Invalid type.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
# cython: cdivision = True
# cython: boundscheck = False
# cython: wraparound = False
# cython: profile = False

from ._util cimport log2, apply_weights_2d
^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pyx:7:0: 'pyearth/_util/apply_weights_2d.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

from ._util cimport log2, apply_weights_2d
from libc.math cimport log
from libc.math cimport abs
cimport cython
cdef FLOAT_t ZERO_TOL = 1e-16
     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pyx:11:5: 'FLOAT_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        self.splittable = False

    cpdef list get_children(BasisFunction self):
        return self.children
    
    cpdef BasisFunction get_coverage(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable):
                                                         ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pyx:112:57: 'INDEX_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        for child in self.get_children():
            if child.covered(variable):
                return child
        return None
    
    cpdef bool has_linear(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable):
                                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pyx:119:46: 'INDEX_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        for child in self.get_children():
            if child.linear_in(variable):
                return True
        return False
    
    cpdef bool linear_in(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable):
                                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pyx:126:45: 'INDEX_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        self.pruned = True

    cpdef unprune(BasisFunction self):
        self.pruned = False

    cpdef knots(BasisFunction self, INDEX_t variable):
                                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pyx:153:36: 'INDEX_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            child = self.get_children()[idx]
            if child.has_knot():
                result.append(child.get_knot_idx())
        return result

    cpdef INDEX_t effective_degree(BasisFunction self):
          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pyx:172:10: 'INDEX_t' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
                data_dict[k] += missing_dict[k] - 1
            else:
                data_dict[k] = missing_dict[k]
        return sum(data_dict.values())
    
    cpdef apply(BasisFunction self, cnp.ndarray[FLOAT_t, ndim=2] X,
                                                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyearth/_basis.pyx:184:48: Invalid type.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 165, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 161, in setup_package
    setup_args['ext_modules'] = get_ext_modules()
  File "setup.py", line 22, in get_ext_modules
    ext_modules = cythonize(
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1154, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1321, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: pyearth/_basis.pyx

may I have a solution to fix this issue?
